# [tricky]Searching for multiple occurrences of word pairs based on vicinity. Python

Tags: python, regex, search

I have a body of text and 2 keywords say k1, k2. I want to find all instances where k1 and k2 occur within a proximity of say **5 words**. Now I wish to store 2 pieces of information from this search -

1. The number of such matches
2. The **word-wise** position of the best match. 'Best' here refers to the match with the highest proximity between k1 and k2. *This is so that I can later work more on this match*.

I have a written a code but it is not able to find the match as can be seen below. Also, it does not give me the number of matches or the word-wise position.

```
import re
text = 'the flory of gthys inhibition in this proffession by in aquaporin protein-1  its inhibition by the state of the art in aquaporin 2'
a = 'aquaporin protein-1'
b = 'inhibition'
diff=500
l = re.split(';|,|-| ', text)
l1 = re.split(';|,|-| ', a)
l2 = re.split(';|,|-| ', b)
counts=[m.start() for m in re.finditer(a, text)]
counts1=[m.start() for m in re.finditer(b, text)]
for cc in counts:
    for c1 in counts1:
        if abs(cc-c1) < diff:
            diff = abs(cc-c1)
            values = (cc, c1)

if text.find(a) < text.find(b):
    r= (l.index(l2[0]) - l.index(l1[-1]))
if text.find(a) > text.find(b):
    r= (l.index(l1[0]) - l.index(l2[-1]))
if r<5:
    print 'matched'
    print r
```

Comment: Why did you delete the code you posted? I suggest rolling it back.

Comment: @stribizhev I thought it was not good enough. I have added it back though. Thanks!

Comment: It might not be but it gives important info's such as the fact that kw might be phrases, plus gives to the potential aswerer a good start.

Comment: i dont know whose answer to accept. both are almost equally useful :(    i have upvoted both though

Comment: @Ciitk34 if you really can't choose between them, just flip a coin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got my own code for this, ...

Give it a shot.
The benefir is that it gives you a list of tuples (distances between words, index of keyword 1, index of keword 2):

```
text = 'the flory of gthys inhibition in this proffession by in aquaporin protein-1 its inhibition b , aquaporin protein-1'
a = 'aquaporin protein-1'
b = 'inhibition'
k1 = "_KEYWORD_1_"
k2 = "_KEYWORD_2_"
text = text.replace(a, k1)
text = text.replace(b, k2)
l = text.split()

d_idx = {k1:[], k2:[]}
for k,v in enumerate(l):
    if v == k1:
        d_idx[k1].append(k)
    elif v == k2:
        d_idx[k2].append(k)

distance = 5
data = []
for idx1 in d_idx[k1]:
    for idx2 in d_idx[k2]:
        d = abs(idx1 - idx2)
        if d<=distance:
            data.append((d,idx1,idx2))
```

Let's sort the data from distance of keywords:

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

So, the closest distance would be the first element of the data (there could be more than one with the same distance though):

```
print "Least distance: ", data[0][0]
print "Index of kw1 and kw2: ", data[0][1:]
print "Number of occurences: ", len(data)
```

-------------- EDIT -----------
So, if you want to consider some multiwords as one word (for distance consideration), you'd have to replace them first, this (untested) code might work.

```
input = 'the flory of gthys inhibition in this proffession by in aquaporin protein-1 its inhibition b , aquaporin protein-1'

a = 'aquaporin protein-1'
b = 'inhibition'

multiwords = ['aquaporin protein-1']
for mw in multiwords:
    mw_no_space = mw.replace(' ', '__')
    text = input.replace(mw, mw_no_space)
k1 = a.replace(' ', '__')
k2 = b.replace(' ', '__')

l = text.split()

d_idx = {k1:[], k2:[]}
for k,v in enumerate(l):
    if v == k1:
        d_idx[k1].append(k)
    elif v == k2:
        d_idx[k2].append(k)

distance = 10
data = []
for idx1 in d_idx[k1]:
    for idx2 in d_idx[k2]:
        d = abs(idx1 - idx2)
        if d<=distance:
            data.append((d,idx1,idx2))

data.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
print data

print "Least distance: ", data[0][0]
print "Index of kw1 and kw2: ", data[0][1:]
print "Number of occurences: ", len(data)
```

Comment: hey, can you explain this line `d_idx = {k1:[], k2:[]}`

Comment: I'm building a dictionary with keys `k1` and `k2` (which would be your defined kewords) and assigning an empty list for each key (so that I can append data later).

Comment: since I am new, the idea of using a dictionary did not occur to me. Can you tell why it is essential to invoke it here instead of an array?

Comment: I'ts not necessary to use dictionaries, you could just use two lists `if v == k1: list_k1.append(k) elif v == k2: list_k2.append(k)`

Answer (score 1):

I decided to replace your multi-word-keyword in the original text since this way phrases can be detected since they don't split after splitting the string in whitespaces.

Then is a simple loop with index and value which makes the counts and tracks/stores in a tuple the positions of keywords match with the minimum proximity.

```
text = 'the flory of gthys inhibition in this proffession by in aquaporin protein-1  its inhibition b'
a = 'aquaporin protein-1'
b = 'inhibition'
text = text.replace(a, 'k1')
text = text.replace(b, 'k2')
l = text.split()
#print l
#print 'k1 -> %s' % a
#print 'k2 -> %s' % b

last_a = -1
last_b = -1
counts = 0
max_match_tuple = (6,0)  # Initialize it like this since you want to track proximity less than 5
for k,v in enumerate(l):
        #print str(k) + '--->' + str(v)
        if v == 'k1':
                last_a = k
                if k - last_b < 6 and last_b != -1:
                        counts = counts + 1
                        if k - last_b < max_match_tuple[0] - max_match_tuple[1]:
                             max_match_tuple = (k, last_b)
        if v == 'k2':
                last_b = k
                if k - last_a < 6 and last_a != -1:
                        counts = counts + 1
                        if k - last_a < max_match_tuple[0] - max_match_tuple[1]:
                             max_match_tuple = (k, last_a)  # Careful with the order here since it matters for above substruction 
print counts
print max_match_tuple
```

A bit explanation with examples about the `replace` part. You replace, in your text the phrase, what you want to detect with something unique that won't be affected by the split in order to be able to use it in your condition later in your loop. So if you want to change keywords all you have to do is to change the `a`and `b` variables definition.

```
 text = 'the flory of gthys inhibition in this proffession by in aquaporin      protein-1  its inhibition by the state of the art in aquaporin 2'

 a = 'aquaporin protein-1'
 text = text.replace(a, '******')

 print text

 # Output ---> the flory of gthys inhibition in this proffession by in  ******  its inhibition by the state of the art in aquaporin 2

 b = 'in'
 text = text.replace(b, '+++')

 # Output ---> the flory of gthys +++hibition +++ this proffession by +++ ******  its +++hibition by the state of the art +++ aquapor+++ 2
```

Comment: Akis, most of my keywords are actually multi-word. Hence, this code might not work. Do you have any ideas with such 'phrase' keywords?

Comment: In your example you want to treat `aquaporin protein-1` as two keywords `aquaporin` and `protein-1` ?

Comment: no `aquaporin protein-1` is one keyword and `inhibition` is the other

Comment: I was thinking in something similar. Liked how you managed the 'phrase' instead of words and the consideration of both direction of proximity (was looking for those)

Comment: @Ciitk34, Akis is replacing your keywords in the original text so they can be multi-word: `text = text.replace(a, 'k1')`, so yes it would work. The only problem I find is if you want to consider a multi-word as only one when it's not a keyword.

Comment: @Ciitk34 tglaria covered me on the phrase part. tglaria Can you explain the problem you find i did not understand it.

Comment: @tglaria I tried removing the keyword replacing lines and put v==a and v==b instead, but the match is not found

Comment: If you read the code more closely you will understand that `k1=a` and `k2=b` you dont have to change anything, use the `prints` if you want to understand better the code. The trick is in the `text = text.replace(a, 'k1')` part.

Comment: @Akis, I tried using the text replace option and replaced k1 with a phrase, but no match was found

Comment: @Ciitk34 i will make an edit to explain it to you better how it works.

Comment: @Ciitk34 why would you remove the 'replace' lines? Why would you replace `k1` with a phrase? What do you think this code is doing?

Comment: @Akis: 'My problem', what happens if you're looking for `profession` and `inhibition`? If you consider `aquaporin protein-1` as one word, there would  4 words between the keywords, if you consider it as two words, then there would be 5 words between them. So this consideration of the multi-words would have to be considered in the distance (but I do beleive this is a whole anothr question)

Comment: @tglaria at first glance that can be avoided if we scan only in pairs (two keywords at a time).

Comment: @tglaria sorry for my silly question. I get it now. Also, regarding your query, you can find the distance after replacing it with `k1`, and then add the number of words (minus 1) that the real keyword is composed of

Comment: @Akis I don't get that, ¿two keywords at a time? I guess one would have to have a list of multi-words and make a replacement for those words.

Comment: @tglaria seeing my comment, do u think i understood your problem?

Comment: @Ciitk34, No I think you didn't (or I didn't understood your answer). What I meant was, if you looking for some other words, e.g., `profession` and `inhibition`, should multi-words, e.g. `aquaporin protein-1`, be considered as a one word or several?

Comment: @tglaria ya, in that case, split() has splitted `aquaporin protein-1` into two words and thus multi-words will be considered the way split() splits them-not as a single word

Comment: @Ciitk34 yes, I get what it does, what I don't/didn't know is what was the expected behaviour. Do you want it to be considered as two words (in which case the present code works) or do you want it to consider multiwords as just one word for distance consideration (in which case some consideration would have to be taken)

Comment: @tglaria thanks for the insight. It **should** be considered as a single word as its a single entity and its length should not prevent us from detecting an actually close match. any ideas?

Comment: Maybe have a list of multiword words, replace the spaces on them before searching for the words.

Comment: @tglaria If we want to handle some terms as one word we should replace them first and then check for keywords. This is a problem of what we want to do regarding the logic of our code and not a technical bottleneck. I talked about pairs earlier coz if we have already replaced a multi word with a flag like `_keyword_` in your code we could not count positions accurately.

Comment: @Akis, yep, I beleive the same thing. I do beleive that would go for another question, this one is answered already =D

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can do it with regex but it would be really messy to support all edge cases.

Simples form is: https://regex101.com/r/zW1dD3/2

`(?P<K1>key1)\s+(?P<BETWEEN>(\w+\s+(?!key2)){0,4}\w+\s+)?(?P<K2>key2)`

Sample data:

`word0 key1 key2 word1
word0 key1 word1 word2 key2 word3
word0 key1 word1 word2 word3 key2 word4
word0 key1 word1 word2 word3 word4 key2 word5
word0 key1 word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 key2 word6
word0 key1 word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 key2 word7`